# Find Max consecutive occurrences on a String Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find the Max consecutive occurrences on a String based on the condition that they can count as more than one if they are consecutive if we have a match of the same word inside of the same sequence but is not consecutive doesn't count, here is an example:

```
sequence = "ababcbabc"
words = ["ab", "babc", "bca"]
```

output:

```
[2, 2, 0]
```

because we can see that 'ab' is actually repeated 3 times on the sequence string, however the condition says that the third one doesn't count because is not consecutive, the same rule apply for 'babc' and 0 if the evaluated word doesn't exist like in the case of 'bca, i have tried with sequence.find but only gives me where the first occurrence starts which is not very convenient to evaluated if the occurrences are together or not, same thing with sequence.rfind, sequence.count gives me all the occurrences but without any condition with .count i get output = [3, 2], also tried with re.findall re.finditer

in case we have a sequence like this 'abrtfhg' since there is only one match that count as 1 so the output on this case should be: [1,0, 0]

```
def maxKOccurrences(sequence, words):
    result = []
    for i in words:
        if i in sequence:
            index_word = sequence.count(i)
            result.append(index_word)
        else:
            result.append(0)
    print(result)

x = "ababcbabc"
y = ["ab", "babc", "bca"]
maxKOccurrences(x, y)
```

Comment: To clarify it, if the input is `aaabaa` and the word is `a`, then would you expect `3`?

Comment: I would expect 5 because we have 'aaa'=3 then 'b' and then other consecutive 'aa' = 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```py
import re

def max_occur(s, words):
    repeats = [list(map(lambda x: len(x) // len(word), re.findall(rf'(?:{word})+', s))) for word in words]
    return [1 if max(rep, default=0) == 1 else sum(r for r in rep if r > 1) for rep in repeats]

print(max_occur('ababcbabc', ["ab", "babc", "bca"])) # [2, 2, 0]
print(max_occur('aaabaa', ['a', 'b', 'c'])) # [5, 1, 0]
print(max_occur('aaabaabb', ['a', 'b', 'c'])) # [5, 2, 0]
```

The regex here detects repeats of `word`, and then divide the length of each matched string by the length of the word (`len(x) // len(word)`), which yields the number of repeats. The rest of the code processes this result using somewhat complicated logic; if the occurrence is at max 1 (i.e., only singletons), then just spit out 1. Otherwise sum over non-singleton repeats.

Comment: I try that and it works for that example but there is another rule if a word occurs just once in the sequence that also needs to be counted as one, only if there is no consecutive occurrences of the same word, for example, if we want to find the occurrences of words =['a', 'b', 'c'] sequence = 'aaabaa' the output should be [5, 1, 0] but if we modify the sequence to 'aaabaabb' the output should be [5, 2, 0] because in this case we forgot about the single 'b' and just count the consecutive b

Comment: Oh alright I'll fix that. Give me some minutes.

Comment: @Marioko53 I've updated the answer. But now what if `ababa` with `word='a'`? Do you expect `3` or `1`?

Comment: in that case I would expect 1 because any of the other 'a's are consecutive so we only count 1

Comment: @Marioko53 Okay then I guess the current code is the right answer.